# Paging by groups of records instead of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a query that returns the following:

```
ID   Rank
1     1
2     1
3     2
4     3
5     4
6     4
```

I am trying to use the OFFSET / FETCH NEXT at the end to return the records paged

I.E. if I only want 3 rows per page and I want page 1, I would pass a 1 to @Page, and 3 to @PageRecordCount below, and for page 2, a @Page = 2 to get page 2 and so on...

```
OFFSET (@Page - 1) * @PageRecordCount  ROWS
FETCH NEXT @PageRecordCount ROWS ONLY;
```

If I need the full grouping of records for each page, how can I accomplish this?

What I am expecting is as follows:
@Page = 1
@PageRecordCount = 3

Return:

```
ID
1
2
3
4
```

I want to return the number of groupings, rather than the number of rows. Is this possible?

Comment: Is rank a dense rank starting from 1?

Comment: Huh? You want page 1 with 3 records on it to give you 4 records back?  Can you please clarify?

Comment: @Becuzz - I want it to return the number of Ranks rather than rows. So you pass in 3 and get rank 1-3 back.

Comment: @Giorgi Nakeuri - Yes it is a DENSE_RANK starting at 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
;with cte as(your current query)
select * from cte
where rank > (@page - 1) * @count and rank <= @page * @count
```